# cannot connect to service hosted in ECS built through cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, connection, aws-cloudformation

I'm creating a stack based on this template:http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-ecs.html

Initially I replaced the image configuration (in taskDefinition) with my own (hosted in dockerhub) but when I try to access the service (via the public DNS provided by the EC2 instance), i can't connect to it. I also used the default template (with the sample-app image) but even that I can't connect to. I'm thinking it has to do with the security group associated to the EC2 instance (but weird enough, it's set to default which allows all traffic and all protocols). Or does it have something to do with the subnet I provided during the configuration?

I was able to SSH into the instance and I was able to verify that image was running and that the node app was started.

Any ideas?

Comment: The security group allows all traffic to inbound or outbound? Is you HTTP port 80 open in the security group?

Comment: it just says "ALL" for both inbound and outbound traffic and protocol so I'm assuming port 80 is open. I have seen it work (through manual config in the console) when the security group specifically says HTTP:80 for inbound, and not the catch-all ALL setup.